# How to get the REST data from API in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code for execution

```
<!DOCTYPE html ng-app="myApp">
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in patients">
            {{ x.area }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/MedZHealth/rest/patient/12")
.success(function (response) {$scope.patients = response.addressList;});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the JSON:

```
{
  "addressList":[{
    "area":"NE1 WX",
    "city":"London",
    "pin":"0",
    "street":"221B Bekar Street"
  },
  {
    "area":"Manorayan Palya",
    "city":"Bangalore",
    "pin":"560032",
    "state":"Karnatak",
    "street":"11th Cross"
  }]
}
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: Sorry but you'll need to be more specific as to what is happening that is wrong. Is there an error message? What is your error message? What happens when you try and do what?

Comment: It has to be response.data.addressList

Comment: What is your error/ problem?

Comment: @nikhil the param "response" is "data". `.success(function(response){..})` or `.success(function(data){..})` is the same. You have to notice in the function the first one returns "data", second one "status", then "headers" and the last one "config"

Comment: @yuro - you are mixing $http with jQuery. Please re-check.

Comment: @nikhil I think you didn't read the Angular Docs. [Click here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) `$http.get('/someUrl').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {..}`

Comment: @yuro - yes, you are right, I mixed up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding '$scope' and '$http' as dependencies to the controller, like shown below

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/MedZHealth/rest/patient/12")
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.patients = response.addressList;
        });
}]);
```

Also this will only work if the backend is also on the same server as the url contains "localhost".If the backend is on different server, you should write the ip address of the machine instead of "localhost".

Answer (score -1):

@PriyamChakraborty

Here is my example which works:

```
//Controller
angular.module('testprojektApp')
  .controller('CityCtrl', ['$log', '$scope', '$http', function ($log, $scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/data/country.json')
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.addresses = data;
        $log.info('Adresslist:', $scope.addresses.addressList);
    })
    .error(function (data, status) {
        $log.error('Status:', status);
    });
  }]);
```

//View:

```
<div ng-repeat="address in addresses.addressList">
 <ul>
    <li>{{address.city}}, {{address.street}}, {{address.zip}}, {{address.area}}</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @PriyamChakraborty I've modified my answer. Please try this. :)